# Proving transient and recurring states of Markov chains.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am new to this platform and also new to stochastic processes. How I pose this question may not be the right way of presenting it here but I need help and I am confident that this platform has experienced and dedicated users who will help me with my question.
I would like to show that
$$P^{(n)}(i,j) = \sum_{m=1}^{n} f^{(k)} (i,j) P^{(n-m)}(j,j)$$

And then use the result to show that if $j$ is a transient state then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^{(n)}(i,j)<\infty \ \forall i $$

Give conditions on state $i$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^{(n)}(i,j) = \infty$ when $j$ is recurrent.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. What is $f$? I presume it is the hitting time. But shouldn’t $k$ be $m$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are not specifying what $f^{(k)}(i,j)$ is, but I presume it stands for the hitting-time, hence $f^{(k)}(i,j) = P(T_j = k \mid X_o = i)$, where $\{T_j=k\} = \{X_o\neq j,...,X_{k-1}\neq j, X_k = j\}$.

Also, I think there is a typo in first equation you want to prove. The correct one is probably the one below (note that I will change the notation a bit to make things better looking):
$$
p^{(n)}_{i,j}=\sum^n_{m=1}f^{(m)}_{i,j}p^{(n-m)}_{j,j}
$$

Now, you can prove the equation above "argumentatively", by noting that the probability of starting on $i$ and ending on $j$ after $n$ steps is just the sum of the probability of each possible path that goes from $i$ to $j$ in $n$ steps. All possible paths are summarize in the equation above, because $f_{i,j}^{(m)}$ is the probability of hitting $j$ for the first time, then $p_{j,j}^{(n-m)}$ is the probability of going from $j$ to $j$ in $n-m$ steps, which is the number of steps left. So the above equations is just a clever way of summing the probability of all possible paths.

If the above explanation is note clear enough, we can also prove with algebra.
$$
p^{(n)}_{i,j} \overset{\small Law Tot. Prob}{=} \sum^n_{m=1}P(T_j = m, X_n = j \mid X_o =i) =
$$
$$
\sum^n_{m=1}P(T_j =m \mid X_o =i)P(X_n = j \mid X_o=i, T_j =m) =
$$

$$
= \sum^n_{m=1} P(T_j =m \mid X_o =i)P(X_n = j \mid X_o=i, X_1 \neq j, ...,X_{m-1} \neq j, X_m =j) \overset{\small Markov Prop.}{=}
$$
$$
\sum^n_{m=1}P(T_j =m \mid X_o =i)P(X_n = j \mid X_m = j)=
p^{(n)}_{i,j}=\sum^n_{m=1}f^{(m)}_{i,j}p^{(n-m)}_{j,j}
$$

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I will go through your solution and try to understand. Thanks.

Comment: If $\sum_{k\neq j}p^{(n-1)}_{i,k}p_{k,j}^{(1)} = f^{(n)}_{i,j}$, then by the chap-Kolmo theorem, we should have: $p^{(n-1+1)}_{i,j} \overset{\small{Chap-Kolmog.}}{=} \sum_{k\in C}p^{(n-1)}_{i,k}p_{k,j}^{(1)} = p^{(n-1)}_{i,j}p_{j,j}^{(1)} +f_{ij}^{(n)}$. How does it equal $p^{(n)}_{i,j}=\sum^n_{m=0}f^{(m)}_{i,j}p^{(n-m)}_{j,j}?$

Comment: I mean I am finding it difficult in arriving at $p^{(n)}_{i,j}=\sum^n_{m=0}f^{(m)}_{i,j}p^{(n-m)}_{j,j}$ using your steps. I would appreciate it if you could explicitly show how to arrive $p^{(n)}_{i,j}=\sum^n_{m=0}f^{(m)}_{i,j}p^{(n-m)}_{j,j}$.

Comment: There was a typo. I did it again using a simpler method.

Comment: The other one wasn't actually correct, there were missing identities. This new one is correct. See if you understand.

Comment: Could you verify that $f_{i,j}^m \neq P(T_j = m|X_0 =i)$ but rather $f_{i,j}^m = P(T_m = j|X_0 =i)$ in last step?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. $f_{i,j}^m = P(T_j = m | X_o = i)$ by definition.

Comment: Barrreira. check the states, it should be from $i$ to $j$ not from $i$ to $m$, in the right hand side of $f^m_{ij} = P(T_j = m|X_0 =i).$ Remember that $m$ is time not a state.

Comment: You are confusing my notation. $T_j$ is the hitting time of hitting $j$. So it is indeed correct what I wrote.